# Old sci-fi short story involving a small scorpion-like creature that can mind control people after stinging them

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A few decades ago I came upon a collection of sci-fi short stories. One in particular stood out, but I can't find the name of it.

Basically, an exploration starship returns to Earth from, I believe, Mars. A small scorpion-like creature hitches a ride. It stings its prey, allowing it to mind control its victims. The gist of it was that Mars became depopulated after the creature has mind controlled everyone.

Any ideas what the story or author could be? Googling did not help...

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the specific decade in which you read this?

Comment: Your creature description sounds a lot like my cat.... hmmm.....

Comment: In The Vaults of Yoh-Vombis by Clark Ashton Smith explorers on Mars find an eldritch horror that bores into people's heads and takes them over, but it's not a scorpion and there is no return to Earth.

Comment: Logic Dictates, in the 90s, but the book belonged to my father from HIS childhood. So who knows when it was written...